# Pivot Table - VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table using a vba macro. I can create the initial pivot table (image 1), but when I try to modify the arrangement (image2) I get an error.

Aha! Got it!

```
.Orientation = xlRowField
```

this is the key and use 1-n for number of events.

```
'Setting Fields
With pt
With .PivotFields("ID")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

'set column field
With .PivotFields("WorkTime")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 2
End With

'set column field
With .PivotFields("OvertimePeriod")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 3
End With

With .PivotFields("Sick leave")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 4
End With

With .PivotFields("Vacation")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 5
End With
```

They do not all fall in line as seen in image 2!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.Thank you in advance.

J

[image]

Comment: You are referring to a field with an index of -1. That can't work. Try using the field name, in quotes.

Comment: @DougGlancy thank you for the tip. Looks like you've stumbled upon the crux. I have 4 fields and they all should align on top of eachother.

Comment: @DougGlancy oops.  I guess I am looking for the orientation and position variables to make this happen... Would I keep all of the variables using 'orientation': xlRowField and the positions: 1, 2, 3, 4? I'll try playing around with these

Comment: "Stumbled?" Hardly! Glad I could help.

Comment: @DougGlancy Cannot seem to format this data all in column 2 using macro. This is driving me mental! any suggestions? See updated code

Comment: So, is it all good? I see you're comment above, but also "aha, got it" added to your post about the same time.

Answer (score 0):

try recording it with Record Macro in excel.
[image: click the gif image for the steps]